# amcharts pie chart code not working

Tags: javascript, count, amcharts

I am new in javascript and ı wrote code for make pie chart with amcharts library. But code is not working. What is wrong? Can you help me. How can ı fix my code?

This is my library js

```
<html>
<title>Pie Chart Trying</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>`enter code here`

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/cinsiyet",


           function (data, status) {

               var turlerVeSayilar = { Memur: 0, işçi: 0, Sözleşmeli: 0, Geçici: 0, Firma: 0, Meclis: 0, Stajyer: 0, GeçiciMemur: 0, Diğer: 0 }
               var personelTurVeSayilar = [];
               $.each(data, function (index, item) {

                   switch (item.turu) {
                       case 'M':
                           turlerVeSayilar['Memur']++;
                           break;
                       case 'I':
                           turlerVeSayilar['İşçi']++;
                           break;
                       case 'S':
                           turlerVeSayilar['Sözleşmeli']++;
                           break;
                       case 'G':
                           turlerVeSayilar['Geçici']++;
                           break;
                       case 'F':
                           turlerVeSayilar['Firma']++;
                           break;
                       case 'L':
                           turlerVeSayilar['Meclis']++;
                           break;
                       case 'O':
                           turlerVeSayilar['Stajyer']++;
                           break;
                       case 'C':
                           turlerVeSayilar['GeçiciMemur']++;
                           break;
                       case 'D':
                           turlerVeSayilar['Diger']++;
                           break;
                   }
               });

               $.each(turlerVeSayilar, function (index, item) {
                   newitem = {}
                   newitem["tur"] = index; 
                   newitem["sayi"] = item
                   personelTurVeSayilar.push(newitem); 

                   //{tur: "memur", sayi: 3}
                   //{tur: "isci", sayi: 0}
                   //{tur: "sozlesmeli", sayi: 0}
                   //{tur: "gecici", sayi: 0}
                   //{tur: "firma", sayi: 2}
                   //{tur: "meclis", sayi: 0}
                   //{tur: "stajyer", sayi: 0}
                   //{tur: "geciciMemur", sayi: 0}
                   //{tur: "diger", sayi: 0}
               });

               var chart= AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
                   {
                       "type": "pie",
                       "theme": "light",
                       //"categoryField": "tur",
                       //"rotate": true,

                       "valueField": "sayi",
                       "titleField": "tur",
                       "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
                       "depth3D": 15,
                       "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
                       "angle": 30,
                       "export": {
                           "enabled": true,
                           "startDuration": 1,
                           "labelRadius": 15,
                           "colors": [
                               "#FF0F00",
                               "#FF6600",
                               "#FF9E01",
                               "#FCD202",
                               "#4876ff",
                               "#B0DE09",
                               "#04D215",
                               "#0D8ECF",
                               "#0D52D1",
                               "#2A0CD0",
                               "#8A0CCF",
                               "#CD0D74",
                               "#754DEB",
                               "#DDDDDD",
                               "#999999",
                               "#333333",
                               "#000000",
                               "#57032A",
                               "#CA9726",
                               "#990000",
                               "#4B0C25",


                           ],
                           "legend": {
                               "enabled": true,
                               "align": "center",
                               "markerType": "circle",
                               "balloon": {},
                               /*"titles": [
                                   {
                                       "id": "Title-1",
                                       "size": 15,
                                       "text": "Toplam Personel Sayısının Personel Türüne Göre Dağılımı"
                                   }
                               ], */

                               "dataProvider": personelTurVeSayilar,
                               "export": {
                                   "enabled": true
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   })
           })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [my last answer about your `dataLoader` section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49109856/6106614), this time your `export` section is nesting too many properties and it's also duplicated. Don't nest incorrect properties inside of the `export` section - `colors`, `startDuration`, `labelRadius` `legend` all don't belong inside of export. In addition to this you put your `dataProvider`, `balloon` and `titles` and another `export` section in the wrong place; they are not  `legend` properties and need to be moved to the top of the object.

Here's the fixed code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "valueField": "sayi",
  "titleField": "tur",
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "depth3D": 15,
  "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
  "angle": 30,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "labelRadius": 15,
  "colors": [
    "#FF0F00",
    "#FF6600",
    "#FF9E01",
    "#FCD202",
    "#4876ff",
    "#B0DE09",
    "#04D215",
    "#0D8ECF",
    "#0D52D1",
    "#2A0CD0",
    "#8A0CCF",
    "#CD0D74",
    "#754DEB",
    "#DDDDDD",
    "#999999",
    "#333333",
    "#000000",
    "#57032A",
    "#CA9726",
    "#990000",
    "#4B0C25",
  ],
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "align": "center",
    "markerType": "circle",
  },
  "balloon": {},
  "dataProvider": personelTurVeSayilar,

  "titles": [{
    "id": "Title-1",
    "size": 15,
    "text": "Toplam Personel Sayısının Personel Türüne Göre Dağılımı"
  }],
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
})
```

Carefully compare this against your code to see what was changed. I also recommend looking at the [demo code](https://www.amcharts.com/demos) on the AmCharts website as well.

Here's a working demo using your code:

```js
var personelTurVeSayilar = [{
    tur: "memur",
    sayi: 3
  },
  {
    tur: "isci",
    sayi: 0
  },
  {
    tur: "sozlesmeli",
    sayi: 0
  },
  {
    tur: "gecici",
    sayi: 0
  },
  {
    tur: "firma",
    sayi: 2
  },
  {
    tur: "meclis",
    sayi: 0
  },
  {
    tur: "stajyer",
    sayi: 0
  },
  {
    tur: "geciciMemur",
    sayi: 0
  },
  {
    tur: "diger",
    sayi: 0
  }
];

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "valueField": "sayi",
  "titleField": "tur",
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "depth3D": 15,
  "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
  "angle": 30,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "labelRadius": 15,
  "colors": [
    "#FF0F00",
    "#FF6600",
    "#FF9E01",
    "#FCD202",
    "#4876ff",
    "#B0DE09",
    "#04D215",
    "#0D8ECF",
    "#0D52D1",
    "#2A0CD0",
    "#8A0CCF",
    "#CD0D74",
    "#754DEB",
    "#DDDDDD",
    "#999999",
    "#333333",
    "#000000",
    "#57032A",
    "#CA9726",
    "#990000",
    "#4B0C25",
  ],
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "align": "center",
    "markerType": "circle",
  },
  "balloon": {},
  "dataProvider": personelTurVeSayilar,

  "titles": [{
    "id": "Title-1",
    "size": 15,
    "text": "Toplam Personel Sayısının Personel Türüne Göre Dağılımı"
  }],
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css">
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Finally I can draw a graph. I need to understand the logic of writing a code. Many thanks for your help!